# ViewState EnableViewStateMAC

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

If EnableViewStateMAC is set to true, ASP.NET will generate a hashcode for the ViewState data and compare it to the hashcode stored in the posted value.  What prevents an attacker from setting the hash based on the altered form values?

Answer (score 3):

The generated hash is **based on form values and on a private key known by server** (see [Salt on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)). So, you could not generate a valid hash while you do not have the salt string.

You can examine ASP.NET sources from **Mono implementation** and see at class [System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/ObjectStateFormatter.cs), method **Deserialize()**:

```
if (EnableMac) {
    data = MachineKeySectionUtils.VerifyDecrypt (Section, data);
else {
    data = MachineKeySectionUtils.Decrypt (Section, data);
}
```

and at class [System.Web.Util.MachineKeySectionUtils](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Util/MachineKeySectionUtils.cs), method **VerifyDecrypt()**:

```
using (KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = GetValidationAlgorithm (section)) {
    kha.Key = GetValidationKey (section);
    // ...
}
```

where **GetValidationKey()** returns the salt for sign and verify the hash...